# How can I read a .txt file into a single Java string while maintaining line breaks?

Tags: java, string, file

Virtually every code example out there reads a TXT file line-by-line and stores it in a String array. **I do not want line-by-line processing** because I think it's an unnecessary waste of resources for my requirements: All I want to do is quickly and efficiently dump the .txt contents into a single String. The method below does the job, however with one drawback:

```
private static String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) new File(filePath).length()];
    BufferedInputStream f = null;
    try {
        f = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
        f.read(buffer);
        if (f != null) try { f.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) { }
    } catch (IOException ignored) { System.out.println("File not found or invalid path.");}
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

... the drawback is that the line breaks are converted into long spaces e.g. "                                  ".

I want the line breaks to be converted from \n or \r to <br> (HTML tag) instead.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried adding this method to convert line breaks from the text file into HTML <br> tags, but it did not work:

string.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />");

Comment: Processing it line-by-line will be just as efficient (if not more so) as dumping the whole file, then going back and replacing line breaks with `<br/>` tags

Comment: Really, a loop going through every line is just as efficient? Interesting.. I might go with that then. Thanks!

Comment: @slashline - what is the encoding of the character data in the file?

Comment: @McDowell - it's a plain text .txt or .xml file and any common character encoding should be accepted.

Comment: Where are &nbsp;'s coming from? It could be stripping out the \r and \n that you are seeking to take care of here.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I'm importing a XML file and I'm displaying its contents after the XML tags are stripped out. Stripping the XML tags caused problems with the /r/n to <br /> line break replacements and I fixed it reading the file line-by-line. In each line I strip the XML/HTML tags first, then insert <br /> at the end. Not sure if this is the fastest way to do it but it'll do for now. Yes, I am aware of XML parsers, but that makes it even slower. Thank you all for the answers, they helped me pinpoint and solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a Scanner and adding the linefeeds yourself:

```
sc = new java.util.Scanner ("sample.txt")
while (sc.hasNext ()) {
   buf.append (sc.nextLine ());
   buf.append ("<br />");
}
```

I don't see where you get your long spaces from.

Comment: This is still line-by-line processing, but someone said that it's not slower than directly dumping a .txt file into a basic String. So I might do line-by-line processing then, but but this brings up a question: Which is faster, Scanner or BufferedReader?

Comment: If you don't feel a difference, maybe it isn't that big? For typical sizes of html-pages, I wouldn't expect a relevant difference. There are so many possible influences (harddrive speed, harddrive cache, OS, file size, java version, ...) that you should do your measurements on a system close to the target system and with similar input.

Comment: Isn't this assuming that the last line in the file should have a line break appended to it as well? That could be dangerous in certain cases.

Comment: @Michael.M: No. Did you test it. Which system?

Answer (score 3):

You can read directly into the buffer and then create a String from the buffer:

```
    File f = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    new DataInputStream(fin).readFully(buffer);
    fin.close();
    String s = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this code:

```
return new String(buffer).replaceAll("(\r\n|\r|\n|\n\r)", "<br>");
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That won't work. I think the problem is that the **buffer** variable is **byte**, so it does not have \r\n. Instead of \r\n it has spaces.. which makes it harder to properly insert <br>.

Answer (score 1):

The code will read the file contents as they appear in the file - including line breaks.
If you want to change the breaks into something else like displaying in html etc, you will either need to post process it or do it by reading the file line by line. Since you do not want the latter, you can replace your return by following which should do the conversion -

```
return (new String(buffer)).replaceAll("\r[\n]?", "<br>");
```

Comment: This also didn't work. I think the problem is that the **buffer** variable is **byte**, so the \r\n are probably stripped away. Instead of \r\n it has spaces.. which makes it harder to properly insert <br>.

Comment: \r and \n are ascii 10 and 13 respectively. I dont agree with they cant fit in byte. Try the replace anyways - I see no reason why it wont work otherwise you need to inspect your source file if it has any of those characters. Or try the code with any other text file created using notepad etc. If you see any changes, you will need to tell us what kind of text file you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("myfile.txt");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int numRead = 0;
            try {
                while((numRead = is.read(bytes)) != -1)
                    sb.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));
            }
            catch(IOException e) {

            }
            is.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {

        }
```

your resulting `String`: `String result = sb.toString();`

then replace whatever you want in this `result`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(InputStream is) to get file content as String. There you can pass InputStream object which you will get from

```
getAssets().open("xml2json.txt")    *<<- belongs to Android, which returns InputStream*
```

in your Activity. To get String use this :

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString((getAssets().open("xml2json.txt")));
```

So,

```
String xml = IOUtils.toString(*pass_your_InputStream_object_here*);
```

Comment: Isn't `getAssets` specific to Android?

Comment: @demongolem Yes. But IOUtils class is of java and its method toString  will work as solution. I agree, i need to be specific in ans. Thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the general approach by @Sanket Patel, but using Commons I/O you would likely want [File Utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File)).

So your code word look like:

```
String myString = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(filePath));
```

There is also another version to specify an alternate character encoding.